# How to make a basic chrome extension to block certain websites?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

What I have so far:

manifest.json

```html
{
  "name": "Testing",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Hi there.",
  "background": {
 "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "icons": {
    "128" : "images/test.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/test2.png",
    "default_title": "test"
  },
  "permissions": [
 "webRequest",
 "webRequestBlocking",
 "https://www.google.com/*",
 "http://www.dictionary.com/*"
  ]
}
```

background.js

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) { 
  return {cancel: true}; 
 },
 {urls: ["https://www.google.com", "http://www.dictionary.com/*"]},
 ["blocking"]);
```

I was hoping that by loading this unpacked extension, it would "block" the listed websites (testing with Google.com and dictionary.com). I'm not sure how the blocking functionality actually works, but I figured either the website wouldn't load or it would display some sort of general error.

However, nothing seems to happen, so I'm guessing that either my understanding of "blocking" is flawed and/or my code isn't written correctly. I based my code off these references:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/extensions/catblock/manifest.json
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/extensions/catblock/background.js
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

"The following example achieves the same goal in a more efficient way because requests that are not targeted to www.evil.com do not need to be passed to the extension:

```
  chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) { return {cancel: true}; },
    {urls: ["*://www.evil.com/*"]},
    ["blocking"]); "
```

This is my 1st time attempting to make a chrome extension, and I'm not really familiar with html or javascript, so apologies if I'm way off the mark with my implementation.

Comment: ALWAYS use the devtools debugger. In this case [for the background page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029). You'll see an error: `https://www.google.com` is not a valid pattern. Simply add `/*`

Comment: @wOxxOm ok, I changed both entries to *://*.google.com/  I checked the debugger tool, and I don't see any errors, but the extension still doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Apparently you didn't reload the extension. There's a `Reload` action link on chrome://extensions page.

Comment: @wOxxOm I managed to get it working using:                               `function blockRequest(details) { 
    return {cancel: true};
}

function updateFilters(urls) {
   if(chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.hasListener(blockRequest))
 chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(blockRequest);
   chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(blockRequest, {urls: ["*://*.google.com/*"]}, ['blocking']);
}

updateFilters();  `    Not sure why the previous implementation didn't work.

Comment: The originally posted code just works when you add `/*`. No need to remove the listener. It does nothing because the API doesn't register a second copy of the listener anyway. If it doesn't work for you, there's something else you're doing wrong.

Comment: @wOxxOm You are correct, I just removed the "if(chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.hasListener(blockReques‌​t)) chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(blockReque‌​st); " and it still works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: P.S.: I figured out that in my 1st post, for background.js I needed to put that code inside a function and call it. For some reason, I thought it would just run automatically. So now the code from my 1st post works as well!

Comment: Just in case I wasn't clear, the originally posted code works just fine when I add `/*`.

Answer (score 5):

### Here is the code for the [site-blocking extension](https://github.com/sak1sham/LaserFocus) that I made.

---

Following is the **manifest.json** file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "SiteBlocker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Block non-important info from your browsers",

  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
  }],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icons8-fire-96.png", //change this icon to your icon file
      "default_popup": "small_win.html"
    }
}
```

Here is the **content.js** file which contains the main code:

```
//BLOCK WORDS
findString = function findText(text) {
  if(window.find(text)){
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = '';
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = 'This site is blocked';
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  };
}

findString("WordToBlock");

//BLOCK THE PARTIAL DOMAINS
findURL = function changeURL(text){
  var current = window.location.href;
  if(current === text){
    window.location.replace("https://www.google.co.in");
  }
}

//BLOCK THE ENTIRE DOMAIN WITH THE FOLLOWING FUNCTION
findAllURL = function changeAllURL(text){
  var current = window.location.href;
  if(current.startsWith(text)){
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = '';
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = 'Domain is blocked';
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  }
}


findURL("https://www.quora.com/");
findAllURL("https://www.facebook.com/");
```

And here is the **small_win.html** file which opens a popup when you click the icon of the extension:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style media="screen">
      body {
          min-width:500px;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  Add the content of the popup window
</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the link to my github repository: https://github.com/sak1sham/LaserFocus which contains the code for the extension.

Thank you